# Numpy array dimension conversion

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimension array which sub-array has different size, it is expected to operate as 2 dimension array but turns out 1, is there anything wrong?

```py
import numpy as np
sample_list = [['Section 1','Section 2','Section 3'],['Section 4','Section 5'],['Section 6']]
nd_array = np.array(sample_list, dtype=object)
print(nd_array.ndim)
```

the output is 1
however, when it change to

```py
import numpy as np
sample_list = [['Section 1','Section 2','Section 3'],['Section 4','Section 5','Section 6'],['Section 7','Section 7','Section 7']]
nd_array = np.array(sample_list, dtype=object)
print(nd_array.ndim)
```

the output is as expected is 2.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong, except that your first array is not a 2-dimensional array.  It's a one-dimensional array with 3 entries, each of which happens to be a different-sized list.

Numpy 2D arrays are always square.  You'll have to pad the lists in your first example if you want to make it a 2D array.